# PHP storing array column output from a function i call upon multiple times

Tags: php

I am trying to merge two parts of a code. To do that i have to store the echo'd array column output from a function which i call on
multiple times into an array or arrays on which I can perform computations.

Here's what i'm trying to do:

```
<?php

$searchquery[1] ="jupiter";
$searchquery[2] ="venus";
//can be multiple queries

include ('find.php');

for($i=0;$i<count($searchquery);$i++)
{
find($searchquery[$i]);
}

/find.php echoes back to me a MySQL query which then
 creates a 2 dimensional array for me called
/$searchresult which looks like this as an example
t x (let's call first column t for example, and second x)
|1|3|
|1|4|
|2|6|
|4|8|
|7|1|

and it echoes it back to me, this works.

But, i need to use the first column (t) (11247) output from find.php
which was the result of the searchquery "jupiter", 
and i need to store it as some sort of array in this  current sheet,
theni need to store the "venus" searchquery which is let's say

t x 
|1|3| 
|2|4|
|3|4|
|4|6|
|5|4|
```

and store the first column (t) as an array in this  current sheet.

I am trying to store the echos from the find.php function as arrays so that
i can perform the following operation in the current sheet:

```
$venusarrayt = array(1, 1, 2, 4, 7); //the manually defined
 //$searchresult first column output from find.php which echos to me (t) (11247)
 $jupiterarrayt = array(1, 2, 3,4,5); //the manually defined 
 //$searchresult first column output from find.php which echos to me (t) (12345)

//I need to perform the following operation and sum all of the t combinations

for($l=0;$l<count($venusarrayt);$l++){
for($s=0;$s<count($jupiterarrayt);$s++){
echo $venusarrayt[$l]+$jupiterarrayt[$s];
```

This part works! But i am having trouble though merging the echo'd `$searchresult` output into an array on which i can perform the above
for loops. In this example i am doing it by hand by typing into the php sheet "venusarrayt and jupiterarrayt".

I am sure there is some way to store echo'd array column results from a function which i call upon multiple times into an array, but i 
haven't figured out yet how. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps:

```
<?php

$searchquery[0] ="jupiter";
$searchquery[1] ="venus";
//can be multiple queries

include ('find.php');
$results=null;
for($i=0;$i<count($searchquery);$i++)
{
  $temp=find($searchquery[$i]);
  $results[$i]=$temp[t];
}



for($l=0;$l<count($results[1]);$l++){
 for($s=0;$s<count($results[0]);$s++){
  echo $results[1][$l]+$results[0][$s];
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create nested array to resolve the issue I would give a little example how to do?

```
$searchquery[1] ="jupiter";    
    $searchquery[2] ="venus";

for($i=1;$i<=count($searchquery);$i++){
  $temp=find($searchquery[$i]);
  $results[$i]=$temp[t];
}

$k=$i;
for($z=0;$z<=$i;$z++){
    $total='';
    for($p=0;$p<=$k;$p++){
        $total=$total+$results[$p][$z];
    }
    echo $total;
    echo "\n";
}

function find($word){
    return array('t' => array('1', '2', '4', '7'));
}
```

and answer would be something like this:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 4
            [3] => 7
        )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 2
        [2] => 4
        [3] => 7


    )

)
2
4
8
14
```

This solution will add all the n number of queries first result, second result and so on.......

Answer (score 0):

Clear solution for anyway of further working with your searched data can looks something like this:

```
$searchquery[1] ="jupiter";
$searchquery[2] ="venus";

$search_result = array(); $i=0;
foreach($searchquery as $current_query){
  $current_result = FindResul($current_query);
  // FindResult will be your function which process single query and returns result of it
  $search_result[$i]['query'] = $current_query;
  $search_result[$i]['result'] = $current_result;
  $i++;
}
```

After the execution the code above you will have array 2-lvl array with clear and easy to work with structure. You can use it how you'd like to compare data or show it in the way you want.

Resulting array will have such structure:

```
$search_result[0]['query'] = 'jupiter';
$search_result[0]['result'] = '...jupiter resul';

$search_result[1]['query'] = 'venus';
$search_result[1]['result'] = '...venus result';
```